# Floating IP Association Error - dreamcompute, openstack

Tags: 20.04, openstack

We took the dreamcompute service from dreamhost for websites as an alternative to VPS. As I understand it, this is an OpenStack structure. After creating a virtual machine, it is not possible to associate the public IP with the server. This is the error that appears when you click Floating IP Association.

```
Error: External network e098d02f-bb35-4544-ae12-664aad3d9c52 is not reachable from subnet 9b89ec8f-ca7f-4a43-8ad3-a03ec4589136. Therefore, cannot associate Port 49077668-52eb-4f30-9622-afb0b8124d24 with a Floating IP. Neutron server returns request_ids: ['req-c662bb2f-89c1-4573-8ffe-b000808e52f2']

Error: Unable to associate IP address...
```

It says that you need to create a router, but the button is inactive.

Comment: which Linux distro and version is this?

Comment: You should be talking to DreamHost as the infrastructure is theirs. We are not going to be able to assist you in any managed service such as that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: graham, ubuntu 20.